# Resuming Matlab app right where it stopped

Tags: matlab, save

I have an application programmed in Matlab (it's a standalone application) that needs to run 24/7. If something happens and it crashes, I have a python script that re-opens the Matlab program. I am always saving some of the most important data on a MySQL db, so whenever it re-opens I can grab some of that data from the database and re-initialize them. However, I need the program to re-start right where it stopped. What's the best way to do this?

So basically:

```
function [] = main()    {
obj1.function1()

obj1.function2()

% if it stops in the middle of obj.function1().... 
% How can I resume the program exactly RIGHT HERE?

obj2.function1()

}
```

Comment: You can't. You'll have to refactor your code so that it can robustly handle restarting in the middle of processing. Though ideally you'd want to write it in a way that an error during processing isn't going to kill the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

To get Matlab to run something when it starts, add a line to a `startup.m` file in your Matlab home directory. If `main` is in that same folder, you make it as simple as

```
main();
```

The question is then how do you resume `main` where it left off. One option is to save a temp file that keeps track of where you were and reload that temp file each time `main` starts:

```
function main
try
    savefile = load('status.mat');
    status = savefile.status;
catch
    status = zeros(2, 1);
end

objs = {obj1, obj2};
startObj = find(status == 0, 'first', 1);
for iO = startObj:length(objs)
    iObj = objs{iO};

    iObj.function1();
    status(1) = 1; 
    save('status.mat', 'status')
end
```

The above code obviously hasn't been tested and is illustrative.